# Can I install two independent gfci outlets in one double-gang box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, laundry

Cam I have two GFCIs connected to one double gang box in my laundry room and if so can I do a single line connection so that they both can work independently?

I have a 12/2 going from the panel through conduit (copper wire) to the double gang box. I want to have each GFCI to run independently without using the load. Why, in case one shuts off the other isn't affected. the double gang box is standard. the device is a Leviton 20 amps. I was told that you can run 12/2 from the panel to the first GFCI black and white. Then connect the second GFCI using a jumper and attaching it to he second GFCI. Is this acceptable by code. we use a washer,dryer in the laundry and the garage heavy machinery. so why should this be a problem running two independent?

Comment: Can you post a photo of the inside of said box?

Comment: If they're in the same box and fed by the same line, why would you want them to be independent? For more plugs, add a regular outlet connected to the load side of the GFI. If you're actually tripping your GFCIs enough that you want to isolate some of your appliances from others, you might have a bigger problem...

Comment: @ShimonRura  if separate protection is required. Say one is a freezer and another is an RV that's plugged in 24x7.   You don't want it raining, causing a trip on the RV and having that shut off the freezer, spoiling a grand worth of meat.

Answer (score 4):

Take the incoming hot (black) and wirenut it to black pigtails going to the brass LINE HOT screws on each GFCI.  Take the incoming neutral (white) and wirenut it to white pigtails going to the silver LINE NEUTRAL screws on each GFCI.  Take all the grounds and wirenut them to each other and to bare pigtails to the green ground screws on each GFCI -- if you're in metal conduit with metal boxes, simply get self-grounding GFCIs instead.

With a single 12-2 and two yokes, you'll be nowhere near box fill for a double gang box, by the way.

Comment: Thank you all for contributing. Ed beal on Jan 10 at 14:05 was the answer that best fits what I wanted. Pigtail will work as well, but when you run it in a series as mentioned do you lose voyage power as Ed might be hinting?

Comment: @larrypinsky -- I don't know what you're referring to as Ed didn't hint at that at all.  Please accept Ed's answer by the way so that this question doesn't sit out here sticking out like a sore thumb!

Comment: @larrypinsky nobody here is talking about wiring these things in series. Is that actually what *you* are talking about? If so, why? Pigtailed connections are the only answer being suggested here, unless you're feeding two different circuits into that box. There would be no point in connecting a second gfci to the load side of the first one. When the first one trips, there would be no power supplying the second one anyway. What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Craig see ed beal Jan 18 2:04 pm was what I am accomplishing. They don't have to be pigtailed. Thank you. Also levinton just told me it was okay according to Nec that I wire the first gfci from the box using a jumper to the second gfci and so forth with the neutral. This is coming straight from the. Panel and ends at the second Gfci. .I jalso have no problem pig tailing but why make it more complicated. Thank you and I do appreciate your help

Comment: Craig meant to say also I was talking only about the line side and nothing with load. This keeps them iindepwnd of each other.

Answer (score 2):

A double gang box will be able to hold 2 separate GFCI outlets. The only question would be on the box fill calculation if they are fed from separate circuits and then have additional devices on their load side a deep box may be needed. If both GFCI's are fed from the same circuit and no or 1 cable feeding additional devices you should be fine. If you post the size of the box, wire size and how many circuits in and out of the box we can tell you if it is code compliant. (I would guess the wire size is 12 since you want to use 20 amp GFCI's ) but some people want 20 amp devices on 15 amp circuits just want to make sure we give you correct information.

Comment: 2 12 GAUGE WIRE -1 CIRCUIT COMING FROM MAIN PANEL-LIKE GARAGE FOR OTHER APPLIANCES. SO WHY CAN'T IT BE DONE TO HAVE IT INDEPENDENT?

Comment: You can have the GFCI's operate independently by wiring the feed from the panel to the line side of each GFCI. Then use the load side of 1 GFCI for the feed to other devices. This will provide independent gfci protection for the outlet that has no other devices and the one that feeds other devices. the box fill will be fine in a double gang with only 2 devices and 2 sets of #12. if there is no equipment ground only 2 wires each device needs to be labeled "no equipment ground" if it is 12-2 with ground, no labeling is required. (please turn of all caps, CAPS are considered yelling).

Comment: thank you...but i thought i saw on sparky channel that you can using a levinton device, be able to run from the panel 12/2 to the first gfci black and then use a jumper cable and connect another black or red to the second.  same holds true with the neutral. I have conduit.  this way it is running independent.. they showed no load? please advise one more time? thank you.

Comment: the GFCI's are wired from the line side of the 1 circuit. A pig tail or jumper between them will power both on the line side with both the hot / black to brass colored screw and neutral white to the silver screw, then the grounds to the green screws. If there are any additional outlets in the garage fed from this it needs to come from 1 of the 2 GFCI load terminals. I am not sure what you mean by showing no load... GFCI's don't require a load to function.  Verify that the line from the breaker is turned on and you connected to the "line" side of the GFCI's if correct test will trip then reset

Comment: I ran out of space but you may need to press the reset button on the GFCI's , some models trip with power loss but it is always a good idea to test them by pushing the test button then press the reset and if properly wired they should work. I am a professional sparky and have wired 1 or 2  in the past.

Comment: Ed it was your answered on Jan 18 at 2:04 which levition also confirmed. Thank you

Comment: Again thank you all. I understand your rationale. Appreciate all your belp

Comment: I'm no expert, but what other electricians told me recently there would be nO problem connecting two gfci in a double gang box without pigtailing from the panel. Again one hot wire goes to the first hot gfci and then have a jumper goes to the second only on the line side with the levinton receptacle. The neutral would also does the same thing. Why wouldn't you want two independent gfci in a double gang box that is an end run especially in a laundry room. If one goes out then You have the other available. We have an iron and one other item connected that would be connected to the second.thank u

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely.  Pigtail or jumper (if allowed).

Start by taping over the LOAD terminals on each GFCI, as you will not be using them.

### Jumper (if allowed)

This won't work unless your *first* GFCI receptacle is *listed* for two-wire connection.  Typically GCI's have only one screw or one backstab, and you can't use both at once.  And in particular you can't use backstabs with 12 AWG wire.

However, some receptacles, particularly the better Levitons, don't have backstabs but instead have screw-secured clamps - like a backstab except you tighten the screw to clamp it.  Those often accept 2 wires.    That is the kind you need to do this.

### U-loop connections

I'm not a fan of this, but some people strip an inch of insulation off the feed wire, about 8" back from the end,   They bend the bared wire into a U-shape.  Then they hook the U over the terminal screw on the first receptacle, shape it tight, and tighten the screw.

When the first outlet is done, then you attach the remaining tail to the second outlet in the normal fashion.

### Pigtails

This method is much easier if you are straining to reach the receptacle location.

Attach 6" of black, white and green pigtails to the LINE side of each of the two GFCI receptacles.  You can do this anywhere convenient, i.e. the bench.

Then get three wire nuts.  Nut together both outlet blacks(hots) with the supply black/hot.   Do the same with the whites/neutrals.  Do the same with the grounds.

Test, button everything up, and done.

Comment: Well, *actual* box fill -- wires that do not leave the box don't get charged to the box fill accounting as per this quote from 314.16(B)(1): "A conductor, no part of which leaves the box, shall not be counted."

Comment: Works perfects using the jumper.