# two gfci connected to a double gang box

Tags: gfci

Im sorry, but i just want to make clear.  I have a 12/2 going from the panel through conduit (copper wire) to the double gang box.  I want to have each gfci to run independently without using the load.  Why, in case one shuts off the other isn't affected. the double gang box is standard.  the device is a leviton 20 amps.  I was told that you can run 12/2 from the panel to the first gfci black and white.  Then connect the second gfci using a jumper and attaching it to he second gfci.  Is this acceptable by code. we use a washer,dryer in the laundry and the garage heavy machinery.  so why should this be a problem running two independent? please advise and again thank you. larry

Comment: Is this related to your [previous question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/105943/two-20-amp-gfcis-to-one-gang-box-in-the-laundry-room)?

Comment: I've edited the text from here into the other question, and have marked this for deletion.